# Call to date parameterized stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am writing a new stored procedure with a date parameter.

For example:

```
procedure test(future_date DATE);
```

In this procedure, I have a query which checks for the date column and need to retrieve records:

```
select * 
from test_table 
where f_date < future_date;
```

I tried to call this procedure like this:

```
test('10-JAN-2024');
test(to_date('05-JAN-2024', 'dd-MM-yy'));
```

but it is not working, it's not retrieving any of the rows.

What could be the issue here? How to properly execute the procedure with a date parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Try to learn how to convert **string to date**.

Following are few examples:

```
-- format of date in string and date format must match
to_date('05-JAN-2024', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
to_date('05-01-2024', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
-- date literal which accepts date in YYYY-MM-DD format
DATE '2024-01-05'
```

so call your procedure using one of the above examples as follows:

```
test(to_date('05-JAN-2024', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
```